# Issue checking whether user is a bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to check if the user is the Discord voice channel is a bot and also check that if there are no other members in the voice channel to pause the bot from playing.

The issue I'm getting is that my check is not doing as intended and will play music when the channel is has no other person in it other than itself.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print(f"I'm online!")

channel = bot.get_channel(channelID)
the_guild = bot.get_guild(GuildID)
voice = await channel.connect()

for member in the_guild.members:
    if member.voice == bot is not None and member is None:
        voice.pause()
        print("paused")
else:
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("Media_URL")) # #default channel
```

Id anyone could help me out here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This `member.voice == bot` is either `True` or `False`, right? So it's never `None`. What were you trying to accomplish here? Also, there's an indentation issue in your first async command, so I don't know if your else statement referring to the `for` or `if`.

Comment: Also, try to place parentheses, it's often down to that. `if (cond1) and (member is None):`

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement doesn't make any sense at all, first you're checking if `member.voice == bot` (which returns a boolean) and then checking if the result of it, is not a `NoneType`, you're also checking if `member is None` that also doesn't make any sense.

You can simply iterate through every member of `channel.members` and check if it's a bot with `Member.bot`

```py
for member in channel.members:
    if member.bot:
        voice.pause()
        print("Paused")
```

There's a flaw here though, it will stop playing music if ANY of the members in the voice channel is a bot. You can check how many bots are in the voice channel and then compare it to the total count of the members in the channel:

```py
counter = 0

for member in channel.members:
    if member.bot:
        counter += 1

if counter == len(channel.members):
    voice.pause()
    print("Paused")
```

If you want a shorter version:

```py
counter = len([member for member in channel.members if member.bot])

if counter == len(channel.members):
    voice.pause()
    print("Paused")
```

#### Reference:

- [`VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members)
- [`Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.bot)
- [`VoiceChannel.connect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect)